# Has Instagram changed their API ,Not able to fetch Followers details for any public user

Tags: instagram-api

Has Instagram changed their API ??,I am not able to fetch Followers details even for public users .But Site like Crowdbabble ,Magi Matrics has access to the follower details for any user .How is this possible ,What am I supposed to do if I wanted to get the follower details for any User using Instagram  API .I am Using "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN " this query to fetch the data ,replacing user id by by friends user id who is there in my sandbox list but still getting **API Not Allowed Error.**

Answer (score 0):

The public APIs do not support getting user followers/following other than the authenticated user's

This change was in effect after June 1st 2016 API changes.